# Running Elasticsearch with Docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I installed Elasticsearch in my image based on `ubuntu:16.04`.

And start the service using

```
RUN service elasticsearch start
```

but, it was not started.

If I go into the container and run it, it starts.

I want to run the service and dump the index when I create the image, below is a part of my Dockerfile.

How do I start Elasticsearch in the Dockerfile?

```
#install OpenJDK-8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && apt-get install -y ant && apt-get clean

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates-java && apt-get clean
RUN update-ca-certificates -f

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME

#download ES
RUN wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
RUN echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-6.x.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y elasticsearch

RUN service elasticsearch start
```

Comment: Just curious why docket hub's elastisesrch image was not used?

Comment: Because, I want to run my system on ubuntu. Is not there only centos in the docker hub?

Answer (score 3):

The `RUN` command executes only during the build phase. It stops after the build is completed. You should use `CMD` (or `ENTRYPOINT`) instead:

```
CMD service elasticsearch start && /bin/bash
```

It's better wrapping the starting command in your own file and then only execute the file:

```
CMD /start_elastic.sh
```

Comment: It stops _after the RUN line it was started_, even -- later RUN commands in the same Dockerfile won't see it running.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why not take official oss image, but, [this Docker file](https://github.com/ozlevka/elastic-meetup/blob/ubuntu/Debian/6.0.0/Dockerfile) based on Debian work:

```
FROM java:8-jre

ENV ES_NAME=elasticsearch \
        ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION=6.6.1
ENV ELASTICSEARCH_URL=https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/$ES_NAME/$ES_NAME-$ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION.tar.gz

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --assume-yes openssl bash curl wget \
    && mkdir -p /opt \
    && echo '[i] Start create elasticsearch' \
    && wget -T 15 -O /tmp/$ES_NAME-$ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION.tar.gz $ELASTICSEARCH_URL \
    && tar -xzf /tmp/$ES_NAME-$ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION.tar.gz -C /opt/ \
    && ln -s /opt/$ES_NAME-$ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION /opt/$ES_NAME \
    && useradd elastic \
    && mkdir -p /var/lib/elasticsearch /opt/$ES_NAME/plugins /opt/$ES_NAME/config/scripts \
    && chown -R elastic /opt/$ES_NAME-$ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION/


ENV PATH=/opt/elasticsearch/bin:$PATH

USER elastic

CMD [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "/opt/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch --E cluster.name=test --E network.host=0 $ELASTIC_CMD_OPTIONS" ]
```

I believe most of the commands you'll be able to use on Ubuntu.

Don't forget to run `sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` on your host